# Can there be an array made out of strings pointing to the same Memory Adress

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, pointers

I have 3 strings. I need to create an array out of those 3 strings, when I do it, it gets shown to me that the memory adresses of the strings are different than the ones of the array. Meaning that they dont point to the same thing. But I want that if I change the strings out of which I made the array, after the array creation, that the array will automatically update. And vice-versa.
Is this possible and how can I do this.
This is my code to show that they dont use the same Memory adresses, hence, they arent the same:

```
    std::string x = "x";
    std::string y = "y";
    std::string z = "z";

    std::string letters[3] = {x, y, z};

    std::cout << &x << "\t" << &y << "\t" << &z << "\n";
    std::cout << &letters[0] << "\t" << &letters[1] << "\t" << &letters[2] << "\n";
```

The output is:

```
0x20b1bff730    0x20b1bff710    0x20b1bff6f0
0x20b1bff690    0x20b1bff6b0    0x20b1bff6d0
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a *reference*.

Comment: If you want pointers, you need to use pointers. There are no pointers in your code at present.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"after the array creation, that the array will automatically update"* - your array stores copies of the original string objects, it doesn't store pointers to them. Obviously you need to change something if you want them to be linked

Comment: Your array `letters` contains *copies* of the strings you add to the array. `letters[0]` is a different object from `x`.

Comment: BTW what you are printing is addresses of **variables** and **array elements** not addresses of strings. Obviously different variables and array elements **never** have the same address. But this isn't relevant to your question. The answer to your question is to explicitly use pointers (or references) in your code, since that is what it seems you want

Comment: It looks like you're either looking for references or pointers (both mentioned above) or possible something like [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) if you want to create a "reference" to the actual string contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here some code using pointers, that does what you want

```
std::string* xp = new std::string("x");
std::string* yp = new std::string("y");
std::string* zp = new std::string("z");

std::string* letters[3] = { xp, yp, zp };

*xp = "X"; // changes *xp and *letters[0], since xp == letters[0]
```

Now raw pointers are a bad idea, so the above should be written using smart pointers

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<std::string> xp = std::make_shared<std::string>("x");
std::shared_ptr<std::string> yp = std::make_shared<std::string>("y");
std::shared_ptr<std::string> zp = std::make_shared<std::string>("z");

std::shared_ptr<std::string> letters[3] = { xp, yp, zp };
```

Comment: Why making xp, yp and zp pointers ? They can be simple `std::string`s, only the array needs to contain pointers to those strings.

Comment: @Fareanor That's possible but there is a the risk of dangling pointers that way. Only the OP can know if that's a problem in practise.

Comment: Yes but IMHO there is no need for dynamic allocation here, it is up to the developer (software design) to use the array only under the lifetime of the target strings (it would not make sense to keep using an array of "references" if the referees does not exist anymore). Your solution works fine though :)

Answer (score 5):

In this declaration of the array

```
std::string letters[3] = {x, y, z};
```

the initializers are copied to elements of the array,

So the strings used as initializers and strings stored in the array are different objects.

You could declare an array of the type `std::reference_wrapper` as for example

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

//...

std::reference_wrapper<std::string> letters[] = { std::ref( x ), std::ref( y ), std::ref( z ) };
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    std::string x = "x";
    std::string y = "y";
    std::string z = "z";

    std::reference_wrapper<std::string> letters[] =
    {
        std::ref( x ), std::ref( y ), std::ref( z )
    };

    for (const auto &r : letters)
    {
        std::cout << r.get() << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    x = "u";
    y = "v";
    z = "w";

    for (const auto &r : letters)
    {
        std::cout << r.get() << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
x y z
u v w
```